# taking off your mezuzah

Tags: halacha, blessing, mezuzah

What happens if you take off your mezuzah because its not yours is a bracha required if you change mezuzas?

Comment: What's the case where "it's not yours."  You mean like moving into a new house, and the previous person asks for their mezuzahs back?

Answer (score 2):

The Sefer Kvias Mezuza KiHilchato (Ch 12:15, pg 176) says:

"If you take down a Mezuza to switch it with another, **some say** that you have to make a Bracha.

In the footnotes he brings Rav Moshe Feinstein (in Oholei Yeshurun, Vol 2, laws of Mezuza, footnote 261) who says explicitly that you do **not** make a Bracha. He brings the Mishna Berura - in related Halachot - who implies that one **should** make another Bracha.

He concludes that - as with any other Bracha-in-doubt - that one should **not** make a Bracha when switching Mezuzot.